# Convering a text file ( containing input like "A","B","C" ) to a nested list

Tags: python, list

Input File Contents:

"A.B.C.D","user","test123"
"W.X.Y.Z","user","test123"

there can be multiple lines similar to the above in the input text file.

I am using below code :

```
filepath = "<path>/connect.txt"

def func(x):
    try:                                                         
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
with open(filepath) as f:
    table_data = [[ func(x) for x in line.split()] for line in f]
    
print (table_data)
```

which seems to be doing its task, but creating problem as well.

Output:

```
[['"A.B.C.D","user","test123"'], ['"W.X.Y.Z","user","test123"']]
```

Is there a way I can remove single quote (') in above output.

Expected output:

[["A.B.C.D","user","test123"], ["W.X.Y.Z","user","test123"]]

List will act as input for below function, which would iterate over complete list items.

```
def cucm(ip, username, password):
sshsession = paramiko.SSHClient()
sshsession.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
sshsession.connect(ip, username=username, password=password)
     # "display=True" is just to show you what script does in real time. While in production you can set it to False
interact = SSHClientInteraction(sshsession, timeout=600, display=True)
    # program will wait till session is established and CUCM returns admin prompt
interact.expect('admin:')
```

Having list contents in single quotes fails execution.

Comment: Please show format of the input data as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input file:

```
"A.B.C.D","user","test123"
"W.X.Y.Z","user","test123"
```

Code:

```
import csv
filepath = "connect.txt"

def func(x):
    try:                                                         
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
with open(filepath) as f:
    table_data = list(csv.reader([line for line in f]))

print(table_data)
```

Result:

```
[
    ['A.B.C.D', 'user', 'test123'],
    ['W.X.Y.Z', 'user', 'test123']
]
```

You cannot change how `str` work for `list`. It doesn't matter if the quotes are single or double in regards to functionality.

If you need to change the single quotes to double quotes when printing or saving the data to a text file again, then you can use `json` to dump it as it will change the single quotes to double quotes, example:

```
import json
print(json.dumps(table_data))
```

Result:

```
[
    ["A.B.C.D", "user", "test123"],
    ["W.X.Y.Z", "user", "test123"]
]
```

Comment: Its not still match with the expected output, the idea is to get away from a single quote and keep the double quote as it is.

Comment: @AmitKumar You cannot change how `str` work for `list`. It doesn't matter if the quotes are single or double in regards to functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `split(',')` to convert the string to list, and `replace("\"", "")` to remove the extra `"` characters from the elements.

```
filepath = "<path>/connect.txt"

def func(x):
    try:                                                         
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
with open(filepath) as f:
    table_data = [[ func(x).replace("\"", "") for x in line.split(',')] for line in f]
    
print (table_data)
```

The output:

```
[['A.B.C.D', 'user', 'test123'], ['W.X.Y.Z', 'user', 'test123']]
```

You can also add a `json.dumps` call (after adding `import json`) in the iteration statement as below:

```
[[json.dumps(func(x).replace("\"", "\'")) for x in line.split(',')] for line in f]
```

Comment: Thanks but , its not matching with desired output structure, as I need to feed this list to another function ... 

what I expect is .. 

[["A.B.C.D","user","test123"], ["W.X.Y.Z","user","test123"]]

Comment: @AmitKumar You are welcome. What differs from your desired output?!

Comment: Desired is this : -

[["A.B.C.D", "user", "test123"], ["W.X.Y.Z", "user", "test123"]]... so would require double quotes instead of single..

Comment: @AmitKumar If you think that "A.B.C.D" differs from 'A.B.C.D', it's not correct. They are completely the same.

Comment: I know , but somehow function which i have in place, is not able to take inputs with singe quote ... i am using paramiko & paramiko-expect with threading.

Comment: @AmitKumar Are you sure? Have you tried it?

Comment: As I know the `'` or `"` is what __repr__() function adds when wants to display it and should not have any effect on passing this as a parameter to a function!

Comment: adding function code in problem.

Comment: @AmitKumar Aren't you going to even vote up my answer?!